# implement UIWebView in UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

i gets **JSON MutableArray** From Web **Contains YouTube URL Strings**..

the intention is to **perform `UIWebView` in each cell**.

my code:
how to implement the code?
thanks.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* arrMovies;
@synthesize arrMovies;


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
        }



        cell.textLabel.text = [[self.arrMovies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"title"];

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ views | Duration: %i",

      [[self.arrMovies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"viewCount"],intMinutes];





        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to make a custom UITableViewCell subclass and add your webview in there.  Search SO for how to create a custom table view cell (there's tons of stuff on the web about this).  Then make sure to disable scrolling in your web view otherwise it will be impossible to scroll your tableview.

Comment: why do you want a webview if you have strings?

Comment: i have strings for load the cells (that the way to do it?)
and after strings, i want a YouTube Slots for each Cell..

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mistaken about what a UIWebView is. A UIWebView allows you to embed web content in your application. This is not the same as doing a web request, getting a JSONString, parsing it and displaying it in your views. I think that's what you're really asking how to do. Please edit your question / confirm this.

What specifically is wrong with the code you have above? What problems are you facing? I think your issue is that you need an `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* arrMovies;` and `@synthesize artMoves = _artMovies;` in your implementation file.

Make sure to override the getter for your artMovies property as well.

Comment: i wrote getter and setters of course,

but i search on google and i cannot find how to present a youTube slots in tableView